# Grails optionValue displaying 'null' in g:select tag

Tags: grails, select

I'm running into the issue that with my grails select tag. If the values in the `optionValue` field are `null`, it actually displays `null`. Is there a way to do some safe null checking and display a blank (or nothing at all) if the value is null? The select I have is

```
<g:select name="epoc" value="${travelInstance?.epoc?.id}" from="${user?.epocs}" optionKey="id" optionValue="${{it.firstName + ' ' + it.lastName}}" noSelection="${['null':' ']}" disabled="${disabled}"/>
```

If the `firstName` field is `null` it will display something like `null Jones`. Is there any way for it to display just `Jones`?

Comment: `${{(it?.firstName ? it.firstName + ' ' : '') + it.lastName}}`

Comment: Viola! Didn't think of a ternary operator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this using the ternary operator, like this:

`${{(it?.firstName ? it.firstName + ' ' : '') + it.lastName}}`